# Cygwin ssh with keys error - A specified logon session does not exist

Tags: ssh, scheduled-task, cygwin, cygwin-sshd

Update: The issue is only on `Windows server 2008 R2`. I created a `Windows server 2012 R2` VM and it works fine.

I want to run some windows query through ssh, but this is a interesting issue which I'm unable to find the cause of it.

The error I get is the following when using keys to authenticate:

```
root@ubunutu: ssh -t  username@10.10.10.10 "schtasks /query"
ERROR: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
```

GPO "Do not allow storage of passwords and credentials for network authentication" is already disabled.

It works fine if I use password authentication and returns the output from the query.

It also works if I start the sshd on remote cygwin server with `-D` or `-d` and then authenticate using keys or password.

Update: it works as long as the service is started by the same user which we authenticate. `username@cygserver: /usr/sbin/sshd.exe`

By default `cygrunsrv --start sshd` starts as SERVER_NAME/cyg_server user.

```
username@cygserver: /usr/sbin/sshd.exe -D
or
username@cygserver: /usr/sbin/sshd.exe

root@ubunutu: ssh -t  username@10.10.10.10 "schtasks /query"

...output of all schedule tasks
```

Other windows commands works fine.

Debug logs when using keys:

```
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env _
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug1: Sending command: schtasks /query
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 88
ERROR: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
debug2: channel 0: written 88 to efd 6
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
    #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)
```

Debug logs when sshd is started with `-D` switch and authenticating using keys.

```
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env _
debug3: Ignored env OLDPWD
debug1: Sending command: schtasks /query
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0

Folder: \
TaskName                                 Next Run Time          Status
======================================== ====================== ===============
test1                                 N/A                    Running

RegIdleBackup                            8/6/2018 12:25:27 AM   Ready
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed


Folder: \Microsoft\Windows\Wininet
TaskName                                 Next Run Time          Status
======================================== ====================== ===============
test2                                      N/A                    Running
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
    #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

Transferred: sent 2712, received 13664 bytes, in 0.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 17373.0, received 87531.3
debug1: Exit status 0
```